# JPQL: error compiling - state field 'e.e2.e3' cannot be resolved to a valid type

Tags: java, jpql, jpa-2.1

I have this error that i can not solve.

```
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT e FROM ResourceGroup e WHERE e.aclUserResourceGroups.userGroup=:userGroup AND e.aclUserResourceGroups.canView=:canView]. 
[36, 69] The state field path 'e.aclUserResourceGroups.userGroup' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
[87, 118] The state field path 'e.aclUserResourceGroups.canView' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

NamedQuery:

```
 SELECT e 
 FROM ResourceGroup e 
 WHERE e.aclUserResourceGroups.userGroup=:userGroup 
 AND e.aclUserResourceGroups.canView=:canView
```

ERD:

[image]

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="resource_group")
public class ResourceGroup  implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "resourceGroup", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "resourcegroup_id")
    private List<UserGroupResourceGroup> aclUserResourceGroups;
}
```

Join entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_group_resource_group")
public class UserGroupResourceGroup implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = UserGroup.class, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="usergroup_id")
    private UserGroup userGroup = new UserGroup();

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ResourceGroup.class, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="resourcegroup_id")
    private ResourceGroup resourceGroup = new ResourceGroup()
}
```

UserGroups:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_group")
public class UserGroup implements Serializable{


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="userGroup", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "usergroup_id") 
    private List<AccessControlList> acl;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="userGroup", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "usergroup_id") 
    private List<UserGroupResourceGroup> aclUserResourceGroups;
}
```

DAO:

```
@Override
public List<ResourceGroup> getAllowedResourceGroups(UserGroup userGrp){

     return this.em.createNamedQuery("ResourceGroup.getAllCanView")
                .setParameter("userGroup", userGrp)
                .setParameter("canView", true)
                .getResultList();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.aclUserResourceGroups` is a Collection and you cannot access it in that way.

Not tested, but try with something like this:

```
SELECT e 
FROM ResourceGroup e 
inner join e.aclUserResourceGroups acl
WHERE acl.userGroup=:userGroup 
AND acl.canView=:canView
```

Hope this helps!